# linear independence of functions $2^x, 3^x, 4^x$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure I got it straight...
Are $2^x, 3^x, 4^x$ linear dependent? I argued that for every x, you can choose the first coefficient to be $2^x$, the 2nd to be 0 and the last to be -1, and then you get a non-trivial combination that equals zero, but I'm not sure I'm right...
And what about $f(x)=x, g(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}, h(x)=\max(2x-1,1)$? Here I think they're independent, am I right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should not post several question together.

Comment: Your coefficients should not depend on $x$. You want to fix three numbers (of which at least one is non-zero) such that the weighted sum of the three functions is identical to the null function.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the first coefficient' ? Perhaps you could write the equation that you have in mind.

Comment: What is the underlying scalar field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)+g(x)=h(x)$ for all $x$ so the second set is linearly dependent. The first set is independent. Suppose $a2^{x}+b3^{x}+c4^{x}=0$ for all $x$. Divide by $4^{x}$ and let $ x \to \infty$ to get $c=0$. Next divide by $3^{x}$ and let $x \to \infty$ to get $b=0$.  Finish the proof by showing that $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$2^x, 3^x, 4^x$ are linearly independent; if some linear combination $a 2^x + b 3^x + c4^x$ was always $0$, then taking $x$ large causes a contradiction as $4^x$ grows faster than the other two.

For the second question, note that $\sqrt {x^2 - 2x + 1} = \sqrt {(x-1)^2} = |x-1|$. In fact, $x + |x-1| = \max(2x-1, 1)$ (try drawing the graphs to see why this is true). So they are not independent.